# Access Aperture library and import XML

Tags: cocoa, macos, package

The library of Aperture is visible in the file system as a package. Inside this package, there's an XML file (among other things) that I want to get access to. The problem is that I can't simply use the path to that XML file due to the fact that the file is contained in a package (which needs to be opened first).

Is there a way in Cocoa to open such a package and then access the files it contains?

Thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using NSBundle will do the trick. Aperture's library is a package that can be opened by using NSBundle. NSBundle provides methods to access the files inside the package.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to repurpose code from the open source iMedia framework.

Comment: Or just use the framework. Depending on the goal, that may be a better solution.